# C++, own implementation of unique for sorted vector of pointers

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, unique

How to write the own implementation of std::unique for sorted vector of pointer so as:

a) avoid memory leaks (stable),

b) as soon as possible fast for large datasets.

The simplest variant comparing 2 adjacent items having indices[i], [i-1] followed by calling the destructor for item[i] and erasing from vector looks very slow.

Could I ask for possible solutions of the problem? Sample code would be helpful :-). Thanks.

I tried to write my own implementaion with the following functionality. Tehere are two indices. The first one represents the last unique element in vector and the second index is a common index.

I am processing array element by element and swapping the elements so as the non unique elements remains at the end of the vector. This approach erasing at once k-elements is, in my opininon, faster than repeated deletion of one element...

Then delete all elements located on the right of the first index...

It is not a homework, it is an serious question. I need to remove duplicate elements from the point cloud (1e9points)...

Comment: -1: Stackoverflow is not for soliciting work being done for you.

Comment: 1. Homework? 2. what is "stable" in a), where you talk about memory leaks? 2. What have you tried? No one will write code for you here. And many others..

Comment: Have you tried doing anything at all with this problem yourself?

Comment: How do you expect to do this faster than O(N)?

Comment: @Chris. I am afraid that it will not go faster than O(N).

Comment: @wallyk. Do you find your answer as polite and to the point?

Comment: @Johnas - Of course it won't. The algorithm you've described is essentially the optimal one, though you can write it so as to avoid repeatedly deleting elements from the middle of the array with a little effort.

Comment: wallyk's comment was completely appropriate. This site is for advice on code you can't get to work, not wholesale answers.

Comment: @Chris. It is a modification :-) of bubble sort, the duplicate elements  come at the right end of the vector... I was afraid slowness but you have comforted me with optimality... Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than rolling your own implementation of the unique algorithm, why not instead consider using one of the [Boost pointer containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html)?  These containers are designed to store pointers to objects instead of objects themselves and automatically encapsulates the logic necessary to handle all the resource reclamation.  Using one of those containers, you could easily just use the standard unique algorithm.

If you do want to roll your own version of the unique algorithm, I think that you are right on the money with the idea to have two pointers, one for reading and one for writing. The high-level sketch of the algorithm works like this: start both the read and write pointers at index zero.  Then, repeatedly apply this step:

1. Look at the value pointed at by the read pointer and create a new temporary pointer to point to it.
2. Advance the read pointer forward.
3. While the element under the read pointer is the same as the remembered value, advance the read pointer forward.
4. (At this point, the element under the read pointer is the first value not equal to the current value.)
5. Swap the element under the write pointer with the value pointed at by the temporary pointer to the unique element.
6. Advance the write pointer forward.

This algorithm terminates with the write pointer pointing to the first value past all of the unique values.  It does not lose any pointers, since elements are only reordered, not destroyed.  Consequently, when you're done you can iterate from the write pointer to the end of the array, freeing each pointer you find.  This runs in O(n) time, which is asymptotically optimal.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help, but..  I am adding the code to an existing project that does not use C++ Boost...

Comment: @Johnas- I just updated this answer to contain a sketch of the algorithm you would use.  Can you look over this another time to see if this is what you're looking for?